# How to resolve 409 conflict error in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

while I am running the script in j meter some http requests show 409 error.

I've recorded a website while executing the script in view results tree it shows 409 conflict error in some http requests.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status 409 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409):

> The HTTP `409 Conflict` response status code indicates a request conflict with the current state of the target resource.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) request. For example, you may get a 409 response **when uploading a file that is older than the existing one on the server**, resulting in a version control conflict.

So it looks like exactly your case: you recorded a request which modified some file and its timestamp is older that the current version in the system under test.

Inspect the request and perform parameterization of the request data, for example if there is a hard-coded date and/or time use i.e. [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) to send the current timestamp.

See [JMeter Parameterization: The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization) for more hints

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are creating duplicate entities due to repeating the same requests. You have to make sure all entities are unique (if this is required by the system). You have to modify all http samplers that create something which should be unique.